# Multi-document view for Google Docs

Tags: microsoft-onenote, google-docs

I started to use Google Docs for my notes, because I was not satisfied with Onenote and Evernote.

This works great so far, their apps and browser support is wonderful. However, the only thing that's missing is the possibility of quickly browsing through the documents.

Is there an app that uses the Google Docs API to show a list of the documents, such that when the user selects a document, there is a read-only preview of the document's contents? I know that there's a small preview in the Google Drive app, but that is too small.

What I want is like the Dropbox iPad app: a document list to the left, where you can browse and select documents, and a large, scrollable preview to the right.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: If you vote for closing, please comment on the reasons. There is a ton of software recommendation requests on SU which is not closed.

Comment: The rules have changed over time. That a similar question exists and isn't closed only means that that other question hasn't been point out yet. You should have a look at [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to google docs directly ( https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/ ) instead of using drive, you get big preview pictures of the first page of all your documents.

[image]

Comment: Well that's great, but the previews are too small to read the contents.